# xslfo: staticcontent overlap to flow

Tags: xsl-fo

I have an arrangement like this in scala using xslfo:

```
PageSequence(
   Seq(
       Fo.staticContent(....),
       Fo.staticContent(....),
       Fo.staticContent(....)
    ),
    Fo.flow(...)
)
```

Content of staticcontent objects may vary. It is causing staticcontent part to sometime overlap flow part.

How can I avoid this? I see static-content has no attribute for adjusting height.

Comment: XSL-FO is usually expressed as XML. What are you using that formats XSL-FO from Scala code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The allowed height of the static content comes from the `extent` property of the region that receives the static content.

Static content flows into one of the 'outer' regions: `fo:region-before`, `fo:region-after`, `fo:region-start`, or `fo:region-end`.

The correspondence between the `flow-name` property on the `fo:static-content` and the `region-name` property on the region FO determines which of the regions receives the static content: you could, for example, have the same static content that appears in the `fo:region-start` on left-hand pages and in the `fo:region-end` on right-hand pages, or you could have static content that appears only on the first page of a page sequence (when the first page uses a separate `fo:simple-page-sequence`).

The `extent` property (see https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#extent) determines the height or width of the outer region.

The content of the `fo:static-content` can overflow its extent. For `fo:region-before`, it might overlap the `fo:region-body`, and for `fo:region-after`, it might overflow off the bottom of the page.

Note that `fo:region-body` can have margins specified so that it does not (ordinarily) overlap the outer regions.